# Not able to set value using aura:id ,in aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration, aura-id, js-controller

Aura Code:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.O2CSubprocess}"  var="mapKey" indexVar="key">  

    <aura:iteration items="{!mapKey.value}" var="mapValue" indexVar="index">

        <label class="slds-checkbox slds-box" style="width:100%;">
            <ui:inputCheckbox text="{!mapValue}"
                              value="{!mapValue.isChecked}"
                              aura:id="{!index}"

                              change="{!c.selectSubProcessO2C}"/>
            <span class="slds-checkbox--faux" /> &nbsp;
            <span class="slds-form-element__label" style="font-size: 15px;">{!mapValue.subprocessName}</span>
            <br/>
            <aura:if isTrue="{!mapValue.isChecked}">
                <!-- tt<lightning:input name="input2" label="we" value="{!v.O2CWeightage}" class="field"/>-->
                <ui:inputText aura:id="o2cID" label="Weightage:" placeholder="Search By Name"
                              class="field"
                              labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                              value="{!mapValue.Weightage}"


                              required="false"/>
            </aura:if>

        </label>
    </aura:iteration><br/>
</aura:iteration>
```

controller js

```
 selectSubProcessO2C: function(component, event, helper){
    var selectedprocess = event.getSource().get('v.value');
    var getSelectedNumber = component.get("v.selectedCountO2C");
    var selectedSubprocess=component.get("v.CheckboxSelected");
    //var getSelectedNumberAp = component.get("v.selectedCountAP")
    if(selectedprocess==true){
        getSelectedNumber++;
        selectedSubprocess.push(event.getSource().get('v.text'));
    }
    else{
        getSelectedNumber--;  
    }
    component.set("v.selectedCountO2C",getSelectedNumber);
    component.set("v.CheckboxSelected",selectedSubprocess);
    var weightage= component.find("o2cID");

    //var value2=weightage.get('v.value');

    var o2cweightage=100/component.get("v.selectedCountO2C");

    if(Array.isArray(weightage)){
        console.log('weightage==>'+weightage.length);
        component.set("v.value",100/weightage.length);
    }
    else{
        component.set("v.value",100);
    }

},
```

Requirement:
 upon selecting 1 checkbox, the value should be 100,if two checkboxes were selected value should be 50 if 4 checkboxes were selected it should be 25.

but, above code is working only when one checkbox is selected, next time giving me an error like weightage.set is not function

Comment: As per your code, if your map has more than 1 value then it will create multiple ui:inputText with same auraId where aura:id will return array and for which you can't set value.

Comment: Any suggestion,then how can i acheive it?

Answer (score 2):

From **[documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_find_by_id.htm)**,

> 1. If the local ID is unique, find() returns the component
> 2. If there are
>      multiple components with the same local ID, find() returns an array of
>      the components
> 3. If there is no matching local ID, find() returns
>      undefined

So, you should first check if its **[array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)**, and if its array you can get length or else you can directly set to 100.

```
var weightage= component.find("o2cID");

if(Array.isArray(weightage))
    component.set("v.value",100/weightage.length);
else
    component.set("v.value",100);
```

Comment: Can you add your code in question, there could be some syntax error

Comment: its `component.set` only. Your code looks fine, why do you think its not working? problem could be somewhere else,

Answer (score 0):

Adding a for loop,for array helped.
Thanks everyone.
below is the code that worked.

var weightage=[];
         weightage= component.find("o2cID");
        var o2cweightage=100/component.get("v.selectedCountO2C");
        //weightage.set("v.value",o2cweightage);
       if(Array.isArray(weightage)){
            console.log('weightage==>'+weightage.length);
           for(var i=0;i

```
    }
    else{
       weightage.set("v.value",o2cweightage);
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. You should have said in question you wanted to change `value` of same input